# Can someone help explain how the abstract class WindowAdapter works?

Tags: java

Ok so if I add a Window Listener to a JFrame, I can add a new `WindowAdapter()` as an abstract class then override specific methods that I want so that I can add functionality to them, such as `windowClosing()`.  `WindowAdapter` is an abstract class and is the default implementation of the interface `WindowListener`, and `WindowListener` extends `EventListener`; all of these are fairly empty and simply define method names but have no real code.

So my question is, where is it defined what the root default behaviors are?  Where is the X button tied to the `windowClosing` event?  And where is the `windowClosing` event defined?

I guess what it comes down to is I'm trying to get a better idea of abstract classes, interfaces, and subclassing, and maybe the example I'm trying to parse through is a bit too complex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Where is the X button tied to the windowClosing event? And where is the windowClosing event defined?

In short, don't worry about where this is defined in particular - it's all set up in the Swing internal event mechanism, which isn't something as an end user you need to worry about.

> Can someone help explain how the abstract class `WindowAdapter` works?

`WindowAdapter` is simply, as you've noted, the "default implementation" of `WindowListener`. All this means is that it implements every single method as a blank method, so you just choose to override the ones that you need. It's purely for convenience, to save you having to define a bunch of empty methods you don't use or care about every time you, for instance, want to set up a listener just to fire when a window is closing.

Comment: how can i find code for windowClosing event just curious?I want to see how its coded in swing

Comment: Thanks -- That is my understanding however similar to Tomas, I am curious to see how the coding is done for the event and to see it all tie together.  I now have a grasp on the difference between implementing interfaces and extending classes and the idea for abstract classes, I would just like to see how to know when I should use them.